# moved config/application.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am still learning ruby on rails. I accidentally moved the file `config/application.rb` into the `config/locales` directory.

Then I figured this out and moved it back, but after I did the `rails generate` and `rails console` commands stopped working.

Any advice?

Comment: What exact error message are you getting?

Comment: No error message, the terminal just freezes.

Comment: Try running `spring stop` and then any of your `rails` commands.

Comment: Thank worked. Thank you!

Comment: What does it do exactly?

Comment: I explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rails versions 4 and later use [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) to speed up the development process by loading your application into memory. This way, commands like `rake db:migrate`, `rails new` or any command that requires to load the whole rails before running are speeded up. Because, they are already launched and in the memory. Spring just updates changed files.

In your case, you ran `rails new` command in the "broken" state, without the `application.rb` file and that application is in the memory. The next time you ran the `rails` command it was running the "broken" code.

So, running `spring stop` to stop the Spring fixed your problem.